# How much RAM/CPU for running VS2015 on a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

Host system: Linux, i5 4210U 2 cores / 4 threads, 8 GB RAM
Guest system: Win10, Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

How much RAM and how many CPUs should I assign to the VM to ensure a smooth experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely on how much source code you're going to be messing with, and whether you want to do anything else in Windows besides run Visual Studio (for example, if you want to debug whatever you're building, you'll need to add its resource requirements to Visual Studio's). 2GB of RAM and 1 logical thread will work for small-to-medium codebases if you don't have much else running in Windows, but I'd tend to bump the RAM to 3-4GB and assign an entire core to the VM unless you expect to be doing a lot of processing in the Linux machine at the same time you're working in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. I assigned it 2 CPUs and 4 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i know,-If you have lets say 2GB RAM, you should set your VM RAM to 1 GB or Less, As if you try to exceed it, the Main OS will fall short of RAM and ultimately hang up.One Tip, The amount of RAM you have of your System, alloting its half would be a good thing to do, and remember, Windows needs at leat 2 GB RAM to run smoothly without errors.

Your Memory allocation would depend on the type of work you want to do on your Virtual OS, (Linux,Solaris,DOS,Debian), Though DOS needs less RAM.

If you want to use Linux specifically for Hacking, its better you allot at least 2 GB RAM to the Virtual OS.